# how to find which process had created any file in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

Is there any way to know which process had created any file in Linux Red Hat/CentOS 5?

Comment: There's a good answer to this question on the Linux StackExchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13791/10822

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any process that monitors these changes/creations than you have no way to know which process actually created a file or did anything.

This link may help you start with files auditing : [Linux audit files to see who made changes to a file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html)

In case you are a programmer you may be interested in "[Monitor Linux file system events with inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify/?ca=drs-)"

Comment: `inotify` doesn't give the process ID; you would need to use `fanotify` for that.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only monitor future file creation by using the auditing subsystem.